# My Bigquery SQL wont use functions such as YEAR or CREATE or DROP

Tags: google-bigquery, create-table, drop-table

I am new to Big Query and I am trying to understand why my script doesn't work. Script is below

```sql
DROP TEMP TABLE top1;

CREATE TEMP TABLE topl
(Language STRING,
NoofRepos INTEGER);

INSERT INTO topl
(SELECT  l.language.name Language, COUNT(*) AS NoOfRepos, 
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_repos] sr
  INNER JOIN [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.languages] l on sr.repo_name = l.repo_name
  WHERE l.language.name is NOT null
  GROUP BY language
  ORDER BY 3 desc
  LIMIT 10 );


SELECT YEAR(c.committer.date), COUNT(*)
FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_commits] c
INNER JOIN [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_repos] sr on c.repo_name = sr.Repo_name
INNER JOIN [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.languages] l on sr.repo_name = l.repo_name
GROUP BY YEAR(c.committer.date)
WHERE l.language.name in (SELECT Language FROM topl)
```

It is coming up with errors for the functions
'YEAR'
'CREATE'
'DROP'
and I am unsure why as I know it supports these functions. Any help would be great

Comment: Check out Legacy SQL vs StandardSQL: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql

Answer (score 0):

You are on an interface where there is still legacySQL.

Check your GUI or add #standardSQL before your queries, also  tables names must be escaped like

```
`table`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the legacy SQL GUI. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql), LegacySQL does not a **DROP** function. You have two options for changing to Standard SQL, first it is via command line within the console using ***#standardSQL*** in the beginning of your code. The second one is using the console, as follows:

**First step:**
[image]

**Second step:**
[image]

In addition, I encourage you to have a look in all available built in function within StandardSQL [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions).

Nevertheless, when you get an error on BigQuery you can consult [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages) documentation for further clarification, it contains the most common errors when using the console.

I hope it helps.